# I have created a simple Task manager android app, now I want to make use of Intent service in it, how do I do it?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, background-process

I have a Main_Activity and a DB-handler class which extends SQLiteopenhelper and Customdapter class extends Array-adapter, Update_Delete_Activity class extends Activity and a bean class. I wanted to know how and where to implement Intent service in this app,
I know to create and implement a Intent Service by creating a new class, however I don't know how to implement it in this app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first make it clear why do you need a service.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: I suggest you do a lot of reading on http://developer.android.com to know the how and where, and even why.

Comment: Ok will do that first.